# React-bootstrap modal opens twice

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I am trying to open a modal when the users session times out. I am using redux-timeout to handle the timer and tell my modal when to open so the user can extend there session. Redux-timeout appears to be working correctly and my modal does open. The problem is that 2 react-bootstrap modals open when the time expires and I don't understand why.

Session.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addTimeout, WATCH_ALL, removeTimeout } from 'redux-timeout';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { OPEN_SESSION_MODAL, CLOSE_SESSION_MODAL } from 
'redux/actions/sessionActions';
class Session extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // Set time to 10 seconds for development
    this.props.addTimeout(10000, WATCH_ALL, this.modal.bind(this));
  }

  modal() {
    this.props.modal();
  }

  handleClick = (event) => {
    this.props.extend();
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Modal show={this.props.session.show}>
            This is the session modal
            <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>
              Extend the session
            </Button>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      addTimeout: (timeout, action, toDispatch) => {
          dispatch(addTimeout(timeout, action, toDispatch));
      },
      modal: () => {
          dispatch({ type: OPEN_SESSION_MODAL });
          dispatch(removeTimeout(WATCH_ALL));
      },
      extend: () => {
          dispatch({ type: CLOSE_SESSION_MODAL });
      },
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Session);
```

sessionActions.js

```
export const OPEN_SESSION_MODAL = 'OPEN_SESSION_MODAL';
export const CLOSE_SESSION_MODAL = 'CLOSE_SESSION_MODAL';
// Dispatched action to show the session modal
const closeSessionModal = () => {
  return {
    type: CLOSE_SESSION_MODAL,
  };
};
```

sessionReducer.js

```
import { OPEN_SESSION_MODAL, CLOSE_SESSION_MODAL } from 
'../actions/sessionActions';
export default (state = { show: false }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_SESSION_MODAL:
        return { show: true };
    case CLOSE_SESSION_MODAL:
        return { show: false };
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: After more debugging I have determined the the component is mount 2 times and never unmounted. So two modals open because the session component is mounted twice. What would cause a component to be mounted twice?

Comment: Could you post the code that's using your component?

Comment: @user222957 I have discovered the issue. It has nothing to do with my components at all. Webpacks configuration in dev mode is creating the index.html file with 2 different bundles and both get served up by express and both execute. So my session is at the highest level of my application and the initial app is rendered twice and hence two sessions are rendered and when the timer is up the app opens two modals. Been debugging this all day and I had to track it all the way back to the server. Thanks for having a look though.

Comment: @mbrimmer: You should post your new findings as an answer in case other s have the same issue.